# Which normal form is it in and How can we change it to 3rd and BC normal form

Tags: database-theory, normal-forms

There is a relational schema :-

```
person (id, name, phone no, address, email, position)
```

so there will be the following functional dependencies

```
FD1:id, phone no, email -> name, address, position
FD2:id -> name, address, position, phone no, email
FD3:phone no -> id, address, position, name, email
FD4:email -> id, address, position, phone no, name
```

.If this is not the case, please do let me know.
What normal form is it in, and how can this be changed into BCNF?

Really appreciate your help. Thanks!!

Comment: `If [there is something wrong with the functional dependencies presented]` How is anyone to know? ((re-)visit [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @greybeard because id, phone no, and email are unique to a person, which we can use to identify other attributes. Or, just assume this is correct. My bad for not specifying this earlier.

Comment: (The is something fishy about FD4: `email -> …, email`.)

Comment: @greybeard I did not see that there, I've changed it.  I'm sorry for that.

Comment: @greybeard its not exactly fishy but also not exactly helpful. Its a trivial dependency.

Comment: Are you positive *name* should not be included in the attributes functionally depending on *email*?

Comment: @greybeard yup, it should be there ‍♂️.

Comment: The relation is already both in 3NF and in BCNF.